# Is Oracle's Java tutorial outdated?

Tags: java, documentation, anonymous-class

I've recently started reading Oracle's Java tutorial and I'm not sure if it is up-to-date.

In anonymous classes lesson, it is written that:

> Anonymous classes also have the same restrictions as local classes
> with respect to their members:
>
> - You cannot declare static initializers or member interfaces in an anonymous class.
> - An anonymous class can have static members provided that they are constant variables.

I did some testing and it looks like it's not true.
Using Jdoodle's Java compiler I ran:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      A a = new A() {
          static {
              int c = 1;
          }
          // Or this one
          //static int c = 1;
      };

    }
 }

 class A {}
```

It threw an error in every version except JDK 17. Is it me misinterpreting something or is Oracle not updating its tutorials? If so, why?

I did try and googled Java 17 changes but I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: I removed the *Oracle* tag. If you check it you will see the tag means *Oracle Database*, not Oracle Corporation (the owners of Java). The question has nothing to do with Oracle Database. Sorry, I do not have an answer, I do not know Java.

Comment: It seems that the tutorial is in fact out-of date, as stated on the [main page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/); "*The Java Tutorials have been written for JDK 8. Examples and practices described in this page don't take advantage of improvements introduced in later releases and might use technology no longer available.*" I was able to confirm that the code breaks with openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20, but works with openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19.

Comment: *"... is Oracle not updating its tutorials? If so, why?"* - Question: how much do you pay to Oracle to use the Java tutorials?  From the answer, you should be able to infer some plausible reasons why they haven't updated them.  But for the real reason, you would need to ask Oracle management, and I doubt they would tell you.

Answer (score 2):

In the first page of this oracle Java Tutorial documentation [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) , you will see that this documentation is for JDK 1.8:

> The Java Tutorials have been written for JDK 8. Examples and practices
> described in this page don't take advantage of improvements introduced
> in later releases and might use technology no longer available.